# Why is React Slower at creating a list of 10,000 items then standard DOM calls?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to show that React is faster at rendering a simple list because the virtual DOM only has to update the DOM once, where as using `rootELement.appendChild()` should have to create thousands of round trips to the DOM.

The console.log shows WithReact is about 1600ms on average and without, about 1300ms

Here is my Code with no React

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>No React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
    <script>
      const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

      let list = document.getElementById("myList");

      [...Array(10000).keys()].forEach((item) => {
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerText = item;
        rootElement.appendChild(li);
      });

      console.log("done with list creation");
    </script>

    <script>
      var renderStart = new Date().getTime();
      window.onload = function () {
        var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - renderStart;
        console.log("No React: Rendered in " + elapsed + "ms");
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the code with React

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Simple React No JSX</title>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
      const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);
      const childrenElements = [...Array(10000).keys()].map((id) => {
        return React.createElement("li", { key: id }, id);
      });
      const element = React.createElement("ul", null, childrenElements);
      root.render(element);
    </script>

    <script>
      var renderStart = new Date().getTime();
      window.onload = function () {
        var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - renderStart;
        console.log("WithReact: Rendered in " + elapsed + "ms");
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Forgive me if I am mistaken but in your first example, isn't it faster to append that many children to a [`document.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) first, and then append that to the node, rather than inserting that many nodes to the rootElement one by one, having [reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow?csw=1) trigger on each one?

Comment: for me your `react` code taking less time than `vanilla JS` I ran both codes 10 times and `react` is faster.

Comment: Do you expect React to be *faster* when all it does is add overhead over DOM calls?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what is going on with React. I get the non-react solution.  Trying to remove the magic for myself.

Comment: Again, I'm just trying to understand what's going on.  My conclusion (I may be wrong) is that for the code above it's reasonable that React is slower because it is doing the same calls itself.  Where React helps, is when the reconciliation step happens and then there are a lot fewer updates needed, and because it happens in one step, that reconciliation only happens once.